# Are there examples of using the Histogram accumulator in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I stumbled on the Histogram class in the Flink hierarchy, but there's no "here's how you can use this" kind of documentation around it. I wanted to do something like:

```
dataStream
    .countWindowAll(100)
    .fold(new Histogram(), (histogram,data) -> {histogram.add(data.getValue()); return histogram;})
    .flatmap((h, out) -> h.getLocalValue().navigableKeySet.iterator().forEachRemaining(key -> out.collect(key.toString()+","+h.get(key).toString()))
    .print()
```

but sadly the `Histogram` isn't serializable through Flink. Maybe there's a "here's how you can use this" or there's another way to histogram via flink.

I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you got the solution for it. Flink API is not well documented as it does not have enough examples

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flink's accumulators are not meant to be used as data types for `DataStream` or `DataSet`.

Instead, they are registered via the `RuntimeContext`, which is available from `RichFunction.getRuntimeContext(). This is usually done in the`open()`method of a`RichFunction`:

```
class MyFunc extends RichFlatMapFunction[Int, Int] {

  val hist: Histogram = new Histogram()

  override def open(conf: Configuration): Unit = {
    getRuntimeContext.addAccumulator("myHist", hist)
  }

  override def flatMap(value: Int, out: Collector[Int]): Unit = {
    hist.add(value)
  }
}
```

All parallel instances of an accumulators are periodically shipped to the JobManager (the master process) and merged. Their values can be accessed from the `JobExecutionResult` returned from `StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute()`.

I think your use case cannot be addressed by Flink's accumulators. You should create a custom histogram data type.